# How to get order details (sort) from DataTables use ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I use JQuery, JS and DataTables
with settings:

```
processing: true,
serverSide: true,
```

It's a DataTable parameters:

```js
uId:641
month:12
year:2016
ownerId:undefined
affiliateId:0
Cwid:10
draw:1
columns[0][data]:affiliateCustomerNum
columns[0][name]:
columns[0][searchable]:true
columns[0][orderable]:true
columns[0][search][value]:
columns[0][search][regex]:false
columns[1][data]:affiliateName
columns[1][name]:
columns[1][searchable]:true
columns[1][orderable]:true
columns[1][search][value]:
columns[1][search][regex]:false
columns[2][data]:fileDescription
columns[2][name]:
columns[2][searchable]:true
columns[2][orderable]:true
columns[2][search][value]:
columns[2][search][regex]:false
columns[3][data]:executionDate
columns[3][name]:
columns[3][searchable]:true
columns[3][orderable]:true
columns[3][search][value]:
columns[3][search][regex]:false
columns[4][data]:mId
columns[4][name]:
columns[4][searchable]:true
columns[4][orderable]:true
columns[4][search][value]:
columns[4][search][regex]:false
columns[5][data]:isCheck
columns[5][name]:
columns[5][searchable]:true
columns[5][orderable]:true
columns[5][search][value]:
columns[5][search][regex]:false
columns[6][data]:isSend
columns[6][name]:
columns[6][searchable]:true
columns[6][orderable]:true
columns[6][search][value]:
columns[6][search][regex]:false
columns[7][data]:missionGrade
columns[7][name]:
columns[7][searchable]:true
columns[7][orderable]:true
columns[7][search][value]:
columns[7][search][regex]:false
order[0][column]:0
order[0][dir]:asc
```

And I want to take order in ASP.NET.
This is my class for order:

```
public class DataTableOrderDto
{

        public int column { get; set; }
        public string dir { get; set; }

}
```

I tryed to take order:

```
GetReport10DataTableInfo(List<DataTableOrderDto> order){}
```

But it does not work, because order=
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QIyW.jpg)

How can I solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: your error seems to suggest that no data is loaded into your datatable.  I do not see a data connection or population of the data into your class, have you omitted this code for the question?

Comment: full code      `GetReport10DataTableInfo(int Cwid, int year, int month, int? affiliateId, int? ownerId, int uId, List<DataTableOrderDto> order)`,   I have all parameters, except for one 'order'